# how to change url from variable to string

Tags: string, variables

how to chang url from $_GET variable to string by php function like this :

example :

orginal : www.sitename.com/move/index.php?id=1 
wanted : www.sitename.com/move/silent_hill

note : in wordpress in the options we can choice how we want the url show in browser

please if someone know how , tell me how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What system/CMS are you using?
Usually there will be options, as you mentioned for the display of URL's.

However if you've got a custom system you will need to play around with .htaccess rewrites. To rewrite URL `$_GET`'s to the relevant page/title URL.

Comment: i don't understand you

Comment: Which CMS (Wordpress, Joomla, just PHP files?) are you using?

Comment: where are you Alexander Wigmore

Comment: If it's a personal script it's quite hard to give suggestions on such a potentially broad codebase. I'd suggest giving this a read:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049